# Getting errors when converting to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The mysql server I'm working on came default with everything set to `latin1_swedish_ci`. I'm trying to conver to `utf8mb4` using phpmyadmin.

Here is the code that phpmyadmin generated and is trying to run:

```
ALTER TABLE `entries` CHANGE `title` `title` VARCHAR(256) CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''' at line 1
```

How can I update this column?

Comment: No, that's proper syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Please check this link for Max varchar length http://sforsuresh.in/mysql_varchar_max_length/

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your MySQL version to 5.5.3 or greater. `utf8mb4` collation is only available at this version or above. You can check your MySQL version by entering this command in the SQL tab phpMyAdmin

```
select version();
```

For more information on updating your database to use `utf8mb4` collation, see this very informative article.
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query :

```
ALTER TABLE `entries` CHANGE `title` `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Maximum data what we can store in varchar in mysql was 255. But after Mysql version 5.0.3 varchar can store maximum of 65,535 characters. Your Mysql version is less than 5.0.3

Comment: Please refer this link for data type storage requirements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: I am running: `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.17-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)`

Comment: Not working. 256 characters was working just fine for me before.

Comment: I am using 256 on multiple other fields and it works just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100214/discussion-between-ashish-detroja-and-entity).

Comment: @Entity you have ask question about Mysql so i think Ashish is right...and it's working .. Thanks Ashish.